# Как задать форму для Activity?

Tags: java, android

Создал бекграунд для антивити в котором задал форму активити

вот так

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:thickness="0dp">
<stroke
android:width="1dp"
android:color="@color/black_color" />
<corners android:radius="50dp" />

<solid
    android:color="@color/standard_white"/>
</shape>
```

Но в итоге получается так, что эта форма накладывается как бы сверху и на самом деле не делает форму для активити. Углы активити все равно торчат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно увидеть форма активити во первых не ограничевает границы в которые должен быть вмещен контент, а во вторых видны углы самого активити...

Как можно нормально задать кастомную форму для активити?

Comment: Вам нужно растянуть активити и изображение по границам экрана?

Comment: @Herrgott Нет... У меня есть основное активити в котором я делаю фото и после того как фото сделано я открывается следующее активити (как показано на скрине) и демонстрирует юзеру сделаное фото. Оно специально сделано на 5% меньше по высоте и ширине чем основное активити. Но я хочу задать ему округлую форму, но как видно на картинке, что все получается не так как планируется. Есть идеи как задать округлую форму для активити?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @Herrgott за подсказку. Действительно [такой вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644030/android-rounded-corners-layout-bug/12651178#12651178) на англ стаке уже был раскрыт и мне очень помог.

В итоге вот так это работает

1) Создаем тему XML in `res/values/`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

2) Файл бекграунда `drawable/rounded_corners.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

3) Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/qrCodeContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rounder_corners"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_margin="6dp" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

4) Описание `Activity` в файле manifest XML:

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.ViewCodeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">

</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте новый `Drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" /> Тут радиус скругления

</shape>
```

Дальше ему бэкграунд укажите фотографию

На [enSo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12651178/6119618) такой вопрос был уже

Comment: Ссылка хорошая, но код вашего ответа не полный. Я опубликовал полный рабочий код. Вас спасибо за подсказку!