# Как убрать рамку вокруг формы DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment, android-dialog

У меня есть `DialogFragment` которому я передаю кастомный `layout` для показа.

Этому `layout` я задаю `background` в котором закругляю немного края. И ожидаю увидеть красивую форму `layout` с закругленными краями, но получается вот такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все вроде как и хотелось, но почему этот фон появляется сверху и снизу формы?

Когда у меня была такая ситуация с активити(было то же самое), я ее решил так как [описано здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532590/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-activity/532625#532625)

Я добавил кастомную тему, бекграунд как мне нужно и установил тему в манифесте для этого активити...

Но в этой ситуации, я ж не могу установить кастомную тему в манифесте для `layout` который передаю в `DialogFragment` , так как в манифесте только активити...

Я пробовал присвоить тему самому `DialogFragment`.

Вот моя тема для него, которая описывает анимацию

```
<style name="DialogFragmentTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>

</style>

<style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/open_next</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/close_next</item>
</style>
```

и вот так я добавляю в нее те параметры которые мне помогли ранее когда была проблема с активити получается вот так

```
<style name="DialogFragmentTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/open_next</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/close_next</item>
</style>
```

Но ничего не происходит... В активити это работает, здесь нет... Я думаю потому, что в активити уже заложен `layout` и оно сразу его обрабатывает, а тут я как бы динамически передаю нужный мне `layout` для показа в `DialogFragment`...

Как избавиться от этих кусков сверзу и снизу формы?

Поправка:

Как стало понятно, проблема в следующем... У меня стоит анимация на этом диалоге и реализую я ее через установку стилей, когда создаю билдер

вот так

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.DialogFragmentTheme);
```

и тогда анимация работает отлично. Если устанавливать `R.style.DialogFragmentTheme` через метод `onResume()`, или в XML файле или в перелпределенном методе `getTheme()`, то анимация не работает. Но зато если не работает анимация то срабаьывает метод

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

и нет никакой рамки вокруг диалога. Но тогда не работает анимация...

Как можно сделать так, чтоб и анимация работала и рамки вокруг не было?

Comment: Пробоали в разметку диалога прописать стиль через `android:theme="@style/..."`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил вопрос...

Comment: А если в тему диалога помимо `android:windowBackground` прописать и просто `android:background`, тоже прозрачный?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нет, ничего не меняется... Я сейчас создать точно такой же диалог, только в новом проекте тестовом... И посмотрю, там тоже самое будет или нормально...

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте в `DialogFragment` прописать

```
@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();       
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.DialogFragmentTheme);
    }
```

Comment: Вроде как ваш метод работает, но только если убрать анимацию... Если опять подключаю анимацию при создании билдера AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.DialogFragmentTheme) то становиться так как показано на скриншоте... Я добавил в вопрос поправки, есть идеи как можно попробовать сделать, чтоб и анимация работала и рамок не было?

Comment: Есть вариант задать в анимации как начальное так и конечное состояние объекта? Если да - просто для обоих состояний пропишите отсутствие рамки. И судя по виду диалога - там тень используется в эффектах. Её должно быть возможно отключить. Вот тут вроде обсуждают подобную задачу: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045726/how-to-remove-the-border-frame-a-dialogframe

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать `Activity` вместо `DialogFragment`. В файл AndroidManifest.xml добавьте новый стиль, с настройкой прозрачного фона для Активности

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DemoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" />
```

Ниже приведен стиль для `Activity` с спрозрачным фоном, т. е. у вас автоматом уже не будет стандартной рамки от `DialogFragment`.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Добавить актовность на экран:

```
Intent demoActivity = new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class);
startActivity(demoActivity);
```

Comment: Да, но я использую разные `layout` файлы... Около 7 разных ... Используя ваш подход мне придется для каждого так называемого диалога создать активити...